Full game re-download after minor patch. How to stop this?
I noticed every time some minor update happens, it gets downloaded, then some patching and verification happen, and then suddenly it starts to re-download entire game. This has just happened today again with 1.4.1 patch. I don’t want to wait an hour every time some minor patch happens, how to avoid full downloads?
I’m playing on Steam Deck and launch the game through Steam client
Update:
Here is the screenshot:

You can see there is network usage on top so it’s definitely downloading something. And below progress bar there are two sets of numbers, I believe the first one is how much to download and the second one - how much to patch/verify.
Also checked game properties, looks like the full size is 88GBs and this download is "only" 37GBs, so it's not full game being re-downloaded
update: to be fair, 1.4.3 was released today and it only downoladed ~400MBs.

Are you certain it isn't something like shader precaching?

https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/3165461141513185316/ Its just patching from what I understand.  Its a "steam" thing (actually I guess more a "specific game title" thing).  Sometimes you'll download a 10mb update, but it will end up patching 15Gb worth of game files, and it takes time.

added screenshot, I'm sure it's actual download this time and not shader precaching

Seems like a kind of large update? I mean not sure what else to say, I don't think its redownloading the entire game, but probably a lot of files were changed and thus are being updated/replaced with their new ones.

The same happened with one of early season patches like 1.4.0c

I now found an option to disable high quality textures, they were listed as auto enabled dlc. The download size dropped from 37gbs to 11gbs

@arghtype so it seems you found your answer!

I am curious why it says 'Update on launch' under the game. Is it set to update when you launch? I tend to fire up my steam deck on occasion and let it just update

@Neon1024 That's a Steam setting; can be auto update where the client will check on startup (and likely at scheduled intervals) and update the game ASAP, or update on launch to only update when you attempt to start the game.

Does this answer your question? What is happening when Steam downloads a little but modifies a lot?. While the HQ/HD textures were part of the issue, the calculated size of the update will likely still be large.

@l3l_aze, no that's about the size of data on the disk, and not about download size. Arghtype, while the answer turned out to be anti-climactic, it's still the right answer, and I can imagine it still helping some users in the future (especially since it's auto-enabled, which is ridiculous).

While not ideal, I managed to save on some downloads in the end.
First, I disabled high resolution assets in the games Manage > Properties > DLC :

After that download size went down to 26.5 GBs:

